# How do i configure jenkins plot plugin to plot all rows and not just the last?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Say, i have my csv with the following values.

"Series Label","Value"
"A","613.0"
"B","600.0"
"C","572.0"

And this is how the table appears 
Build #  Series Label       Value
13        C                 572.0"

Configuring the plot plugin using csv, picks only C. Is this an limitation with the plugin or anything i need to do differently? I need A,B,C to be plotted against my graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using csv seems bugged from the description. Quote from the plugin help:

> BUG: Currently, only the first row of the csv file is plotted, this may be changed in the future. **The csv plugin expects the first row to contain the column names**, and subsequent rows to contain the values to be plotted on a per column basis.

However it works quite well for me, you need to put the labels in the first row, and the values in the following rows. From my tests it will use only the last line for values though, i.e. in the following csv, only the bolded lines would be actually used (and drawn):

```
"A","B","C"
"1","2","3"
"2","3","4"
"3","4","5"
```

Also note, you dont need the quotation marks around the labels/values.

### tl;dr:

If you generate your csv with **labels in the first row**, and the **values in the 2nd row** on every build, you should be good.